# Objects from .txt file are not written to my Jlist

Tags: java, file-io, jlist

I'm having a little problem with my Java App. I have 2 frames, the mainframe is called MasterFrame. The MasterFrame contains a JList + 3 buttons.

Button 1 can add Block shapes to the JList, this will call the 2nd frame called BlockFrame. Block shapes are Objects stored in the ArrayList shapecollection.

The MasterFrame also contains a Save button which will store objects in a .txt file called "test.txt".

The MasterFrame also contains a Load button which will open the .txt file "test.txt", read the file for objects and set the objects back into the JList. That is what actually is going wrong. The save function works, i'm not quite sure about the load method. It seems that it's actually reading my .txt file for objects but it won't put it back in my Jlist.

The load method might be good, but than there might be a problem with reading the objects and setting them back into the JList. I'm glad if anyone off you guys could give me a hand :)

```
import java.io.*;

// My File IO Class
public class ShapeIOController {
private String filename;


public ShapeIOController(){
filename= "C:\\Users\\Lars\\Desktop\\test.txt";
}

// The Save method which will save all my created blocks in "test.txt" file
public void save(ShapeCollection shapecollection){

    try {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)); 
    out.writeObject(shapecollection);
    out.close();
    }
    catch( IOException e){
    System.out.println("Error occured when trying to open file" + filename);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// The open file method which will open "test.txt" file, 
// read it's objects and return a ArrayList of shapes "shapecollection"
public ShapeCollection open(ShapeCollection shapecollection){
     try{
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
     shapecollection= (ShapeCollection) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException e ) {
     System.out.println("Unknown class by reading file" + filename);
     }
     catch ( IOException e ) {
     System.out.println("Error occured when trying to open file " + filename);
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

shapecollection.giveCollection();
return shapecollection;
    }
}

// The code for the save button which works
 private void SaveShapeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    shapeiocontroller.save(shapecontroller.getShapeCollection());
} 

// The code where it probably is going wrong
 private void LoadShapeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    for(int i = 0; i < shapecontroller.getShapeCollection().giveCollection().size(); i++){
    listModel.addElement(shapecontroller.getShapeCollection().giveShape(i).toString());
    InfoShapeJList.setModel(listModel);
    shapeiocontroller.open(shapecontroller.getShapeCollection());
    }   
}

// List of methods LoadShapeButtonActionPerformed is using:

// getShapeCollection()
public ShapeCollection getShapeCollection() {
    return shapecollection;
}

// giveCollection()
public ArrayList<Shape> giveCollection(){
   return shapecollection;
}

// giveShape()
 public Shape giveShape(int index){
    return shapecollection.get(index);     
 }

// toString()
 public String toString(){
    return "Block: " + length + " " + width + " " + height;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Where exactly are you facing the problem?

Comment: Yes i tried debugging, it isn't showing that anything is going wrong. I think the problem is in here, displaying the readed objects to the JList when you press the "Load" button. The private void LoadShapeButtonActionPerformed method.

Comment: The problem is the "Load" button is working when i add a Block Shape, save it to the "test.txt" file, but when i close the program start the program again and i press "Load" it isn't showing the objects in the test.txt file.